# Как добавить несколько авторов к одной книге в Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Есть две модели Автор и Книга в модели Автор создано 3 автора Jim, Bob, Ana
как добавить Jim, Ana в Book?  Через DjangoAdmin можно выбрать всего лишь одного автора. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

```
class Author(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class Blog(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Ваш случай прямо дословно описан в официальной документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте связь многое-ко-многим:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```